# Is it possible to return a variable type to the script that called a coroutine?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Alright, I have a Dialogue system in place in my game. It is pretty simple in its design. Each dialogue contains a list of nodes which would be what the NPC would say and for each node there is also a list of options that the player can choose from either to end the conversation or continue on. The dialogue part works flawlessly. What I am trying to do is combine it with a questing system. Before I get too far into my questing system I need to figure out a way to connect my dialogue system to my questing system or NPC (preferably my NPC). The way my dialogue system is set up is with a Singleton pattern and each NPC would just call a method on it that starts a dialogue with a player based on its local dialogue variable.

I've been sitting here thinking about how I can pass a value from my dialogue manager to my NPC but, considering that my `run` method is a Coroutine I can't figure out how to return that value after I exit the coroutine if I need to. I feel like this should be possible but, I really can't think of a way to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

An ideal situation is to get the `RunDialogue` method to return a variable type(bool?), but only after `EndDialogue` has been called from within the `run` method. If it returns true then assign the quest otherwise do nothing.

From `DialogueManager:`

```
public void RunDialogue(Dialogue dia)
{
    StartCoroutine(run(dia));
}

IEnumerator run(Dialogue dia)
{
    DialoguePanel.SetActive(true);

    //start the convo
    int node_id = 0;

    //if the node is equal to -1 end the conversation
    while (node_id != -1)
    {
        //display the current node
        DisplayNode(dia.Nodes[node_id]);

        //reset the selected option
        selected_option = -2;

        //wait here until a selection is made by button click
        while (selected_option == -2)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.25f);
        }

        //get the new id since it has changed
        node_id = selected_option;

    }

    //the user exited the conversation
    EndDialogue();

}
```

From `NPC:`

```
public override void Interact()
{
    DialogueManager.Instance.RunDialogue(dialogue);
}
```

Comment: The problem with that would be that the function that wants to retrieve the return value would have to wait for the coroutine to end, which would just halt the program if it were a normal, synchronous function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a way to make a coroutine return a value. Requires some nesting, you can have a look at this video if you want to go this way: [Unite 2013 - Extending Coroutines @ 20m38s on "adding return values"](https://youtu.be/ciDD6Wl-Evk?t=20m38s)

Otherwise, you can pass a callback to the coroutine. This will probably do it for you.

Add some function at a point where it makes sense (e.g. the NPC):

```
public void OnGiveQuest()
{
    // Add the quest
}
```

Add it to the dialogue call:

```
public override void Interact()
{
    DialogueManager.Instance.RunDialogue(dialogue, OnGiveQuest);
}
```

Then change your `RunDialogue` and `run` to take a callback:

```
public void RunDialogue(Dialogue dia, System.Action callback = null)
{
    StartCoroutine(run(dia, callback));
}
```

Now, for the coroutine, you either pass the callback further to `EndDialogue` or handle it in here too after the end call.

```
IEnumerator run(Dialogue dia, System.Action callback = null)
{
    ...

    //the user exited the conversation
    EndDialogue();

    if(callback != null)
        callback();
}
```

Now, I made it the way that you would only add the callback if you want to start a quest. Otherwise you just leave it out (default value of null).